# Aggregation $group return fields as string and not as array

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing the following aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
        {'$unwind': "$students"},
        {'$group':
            {
                "_id" : "$_id",
                'students' :
                    { '$push' :
                       {
                        'name' : '$students.name',
                        'school' : '$students.school',
                        'age' : '$students.age',
                       }
                    },
                'zipcode' :
                    {'$addToSet':
                        '$zipcode'
                    }
            }
        },
        {'$project':
            {
                '_id' : 0 ,
                'students' : 1,
                'zipcode': 1
            }
        }
])
```

Which gives:

```
{
   "result" : [
      {
        "students" : [{
                         "name" : "john",
                         "school" : 102,
                         "age" : 10
                      },
                      {
                         "name" : "jess",
                         "school" : 102,
                         "age" : 11
                      },
                      {
                         "name" : "barney",
                         "school" : 102,
                         "age" : 7
                      }
                    ],
        "zipcode" : [63109]
      }
   ],
   "ok" : 1
}
```

**Is it possible to have make it return `"zipcode" : 63109`?**

In practice this is what I want to have a returning result of the aggregation:

```
{
   "result" : [
      {
        "students" : [{
                         "name" : "john",
                         "school" : 102,
                         "age" : 10
                      },
                      {
                         "name" : "jess",
                         "school" : 102,
                         "age" : 11
                      },
                      {
                         "name" : "barney",
                         "school" : 102,
                         "age" : 7
                      }
                    ],
        "zipcode" : 63109
      }
   ],
   "ok" : 1
}
```

I tried in the $group to have `"zipcode" : "$zipcode"` but as the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-aggregation) says:

```
Every $group expression must specify an _id field. 
In addition to the _id field, $group expression can include 
computed fields. These other fields must use one of the following accumulators:

$addToSet
$first
$last
$max
$min
$avg
$push
$sum
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: check out $unwind operator

Answer (score 1):

The `zipcode` value is returned as an array because you are using the [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator, which explicitly returns an array:

> Returns an array of all the values found in the selected field among the documents in that group.

If your intention is actually to group by `zipcode`, you can instead use this as the grouping `_id`, eg:

```
db.col.aggregate([

        // Create a stream of documents from the students array
        {'$unwind': "$students"},

        // Group by zipcode
        {'$group':
            {
                "_id" : "$zipcode",
                'students' :
                    { '$push' :
                       {
                        'name' : '$students.name',
                        'school' : '$students.school',
                        'age' : '$students.age',
                       }
                    },
            }
        },

        // rename _id to zipcode
        {'$project':
            {
                '_id' : 0,
                'zipcode' : '$_id',
                'students' : 1,
            }
        }
])
```

Alternatively, you could use a group operator such as `$first` or `$last` to return a single `zipcode` value, but this probably isn't what you're after.